# Load website again instead of taking from cache

Tags: caching, browser

I am getting really irritated with my browser(s), when I've made something new on my website (changing scripts, etc), save the document and load the page again, it takes around 3 minutes every time for my browser to even understand that I've changed something in the scripts. Is there any way I could disable the data storaging (in the cache) and load the page again? Or is it caused by another thing, like if my website takes around 3 mins to update form the old file to the new file? I am using Google Chrome and sometimes Safari, if that might help.

Edit: My browser hasn't even understood that there are about 20 more lines of css in the style code.

Comment: I wrote this on the subject some time ago. Might help you understand the issues: http://www.adamish.com/blog/archives/255

Comment: In firefox I have a webdeveloper add-in that let me clear the cache: http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/firefox/. In IE 9 if I hit F12 I have an menu option Cache > Always Refresh from Server. Is there a proxy between you, your browser and your server?